# Таблица имен в php

Tags: php

Все (а может и не все) знают что есть так называемые контейнеры `zval`, на которые указывают переменные. Есть и так называемая таблица имен в которой содержатся имена переменных.

Вопрос к знатокам: Как переменная связывается со `zval` контенером?

P.S Вопрос несет познавательный характер

Answer (score 1):

> Переменные хранятся в **таблице переменных** (symbol_table), которая
>   представляет из себя ассоциативный массив, ключом элемента массива
>   является имя переменной, а в **значении хранится ссылка на контейнер
>   переменной** или zval контейнер, в котором хранятся значение переменной,
>   его тип и дополнительная информация о количестве ссылок на переменную.

[Источник](http://kp-room.ru/page/nasledovanie-php)

Comment: Хорошо, ну а что подразумевается под ссылкой на контейнер?

Comment: @MaximPro Ссылка в таблице переменных это указатель, значением которого является адрес ячейки памяти, где находится переменная. То есть указатель ссылается на блок данных из области памяти, причём на самое его начало.

Comment: Если я вас понял то в таблице переменных хранится пара ключ-значение. Ключ - имя переменной, Значение - указатель на контейнер `zval`. Правильно?

Comment: @MaximPro Да, все верно, все очень хорошо описано в статье. Более подробно можно узнать в книге PHP Internals Book :)

Comment: Насколько мне известно в этой книге больше написано для написания расширений php

Comment: @MaximPro и рассказывается про внутреннее устройство переменных в разделе Zvals

Comment: Прочитаю, отпишусь :)

Comment: Почитал, но не знаю про таблицу переменных ничего не увидел, только разве что про внутренее устройство `zval` контейнеров, но про это я знал. Меня только сейчас и интересуют операции с таблицей переменных. Например: Что будет если мы напишем `$a = 10; $a = $a;`? В таблице переменных будет перезаписано имя или оно останется? А если так: `$a = 10; $a = &$a;`? В этом случае перезапишется имя в таблице переменных или нет? Меня вот такие моменты интересуют, а такого я нигде не видел.

Comment: Вы тут? Почему молчите? Я жду от вас ответа, нельзя же так кидать ;(